# Separate locking on two objects in .NET

Tags: .net, multithreading, locking, mutex

I have a .NET class with three methods: Get1(), Get2() and Disconnect().  Get1 and Get2 can be called concurrently in two threads but I need to preserve mutex between Disconnect and both of the other two methods.  In other words I don't want it to disconnect midway through doing either "get".

I can do this with two locks, like this:

```
private object lock1 = new object();
private object lock2 = new object();

public void Get1()
{
  lock(lock1)
  {
    // work
  }
}

public void Get2()
{
  lock(lock2)
  {
    // work
  }
}

public void Disconnect()
{
  lock(lock1)
  {
    lock(lock2)
    {
      // work
    }
  }
}
```

Is this best practice to achieve the outcome described above?  Should I be concerned about deadlocks?  What if there were more than two parallelizable methods - having *n* locks doesn't seem like a good solution.

Comment: Is it okay to do Get1 or Get2 while Disconnect is running or are they mutually exclusive?  I would expect they are mutually exclusive, but from your question it almost sounds like you don't want Disconnect to start during a get, but potentially gets can start during Disconnect.

Comment: I want to enforce mutex across these, so if Get1 or Get2 are called while Disconnect is running, the call should block until Disconnect finishes (and same the other way around).

Comment: Yes taking multiple locks introduces more opportunities for dead locks. If you are going to use multiple locks, the rule is that you must always take the locks in the same order to prevent deadlocks. This requires you to be vigilant when writing the locking code. Also if there more a than couple people tend to write some kind of lock manager, that ensures locks are always taken in the same order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**
I was thinking more about the problem and I knew it fit a pattern, but couldn't remember what it was, then I looked through the System.Threading class and found it - This fit the Reader/Writer pattern and there is a lock for that - [ReaderWriterLockSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx)

Here is a sample class that uses this lock and has methods you can pass in your get and disconnect calls to (or you could just add this lock to your class and follow the pattern in the sample)

```
public class GetAndDisconnectLocker : IDisposable
{
    private ReaderWriterLockSlim _lock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

    public void ExecuteGet(Action action)
    {
        _lock.EnterReadLock();
        try
        {
            action();
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }

    public T ExecuteGet<T>(Func<T> function)
    {
        _lock.EnterReadLock();
        try
        {
            return function();
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }

    public void ExecuteDisconnect(Action action)
    {
        _lock.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            action();
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && _lock != null)
        {
            _lock.Dispose();
            _lock = null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Original Answer**
Off the top of my head, I would probably handle this with [ManualResetEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  You can create an event for each method, and use [WaitAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6w25xa6(v=vs.110).aspx) in the `Disconnect` method to ensure that all `Get` methods are complete before continuing with `Disconnect`.  If you expect the Get methods to be fairly short running you may want to consider `ManualResetEventSlim` which should be more performant for short running processes. It uses spinning rather than event handles.

```
ManualResetEvent get1 = new ManualResetEvent(false);
ManualResetEvent get2 = new ManualResetEvent(false);
ManualResetEvent disc = new ManualResetEvent(false);

public void Get1()
{
    disc.WaitOne();
    get1.Reset();
    try
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
    finally
    {
        get1.Set();
    }
}

public void Get2()
{
    disc.WaitOne();
    get2.Reset();
    try
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
    finally
    {
        get2.Set();
    }
}

public void Disconnect()
{
    disc.Reset();
    try
    {
        WaitHandle.WaitAll(new [] { get1, get2 });
        // Do Stuff
    }
    finally
    {
        disc.Set();
    }
}
```

Comment: @tamarind - I have updated my answer with what I feel is a better solution and it handles the case (which you mentioned in your question) of adding more get methods and not needing to add handles for all of them.